# What is the reason for these changes in Game of Thrones from book series to TV Show?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I read the GOT books long before I started watching the show. Most things hold up but I don't think that the women are getting enough credit in the show for what they did in the books. For example

> All throughout the book series Cersei has used her Gods given power of manipulation, she used blackmail, sex and poison to get what she wanted out of people in the books. When Tyrion was in prison after his trial by combat for the Joffrey thing, Jaime came to set him free and Tyrion said something like 'Man, she's been sleeping around...a lot' (paraphrasing), and she didn't even do that in the show. Lancel Lannister was the only one and it wasn't even a big deal, and it was her cousin (yeah but it was her first cousin).

Why when they made the show did they decide to change that? It doesn't seem very fair.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to answer this, other than to ask the show's producers. Lots of movies have smaller roles for female characters in general. The reasons are beyond the scope of this site, I think, although I'm not a moderator, just another user.

Comment: -1 Hide the spoilers already!

Comment: Spoilers hidden. You realize that is _impossible_ for a TV show or movie to be 100% accurate to its book source, don't you? Screenwriters and producers need to compromise due to budget, time and other restrictions.

Comment: I don’t think there’s anything inherently wrong with asking about the reasoning behind specific differences, but there are lots of existing questions about lots of the differences between show and book (see e.g. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56192/why-does-game-of-thrones-differ-so-much-from-a-song-of-ice-and-fire), and often the premise behind the question seems to be “Shouldn’t all the events in the TV show be the same as in the books wherever possible?” That’s a flawed premise. I’m not sure if that’s your premise or not.

Comment: *I think the question is fare. She is asking one specific detail of the whole series that may actually have a particular reason for being different.

Comment: @Maurizioindenmark that's exactly what I'm doing. I understand it can't all be the same, they have made some annoying changes but this one bothers me a lot. One thing I loved so much about the books was that it made women for that time period seem like they weren't complacent. The TV show doesn't (to me any way).

Answer (score 13):

Your premise is flawed.

Tyrion's actual quote is as follows:

> You poor stupid blind crippled fool. Must I spell every little thing out for you? Very well. Cersei is a lying whore, she’s been fucking Lancel and Osmund Kettleblack and probably Moon Boy for all I know.

We, and Tyrion, actually *know* for sure that she slept with Lancel. And that's part of the TV show as well. But we are never told that she actually slept with Osmund or Moonboy. Or anyone else for that matter. That's probably just an angry Tyrion lashing out at Jaime. The only person we know for sure that she slept with in that period was Lancel. She does flirt a lot with the men she wants to control, but we see glimpses of that in the show as well.

Comment: The reason I asked this question was because there is a major thing (no spoilers) that happens with her in "A Dance of Dragons" and if the events leading up to it never happened in the series, how are they supposed to put it in the show?

Comment: @AlyssaBlackmon - If we're thinking about the same event, then it's pretty easy to insert it into the upcoming season. The first we've known (really known) about Cersei's dalliance with him is from AFFC when she got her own POV chapters.